# "illegal start of simple expression" error in scalajs when use :=

Tags: scala, syntax-error, scala.js, binding.scala

if I use

```
loginError := if (loginItem.username.isEmpty) None else Some(loginItem.isUsernameValid)
```

compiler says:

```
 illegal start of simple expression
```

when changed to

```
val err = if (loginItem.username.isEmpty) None else Some(loginItem.isUsernameValid)
loginError := err
```

everything goes fine.

why I have to use a temporary variable?

Answer (score 3):

You need parentheses around your if expression in the first case, because (in layman's terms) the if has a lower precedence than the `:=`:

```
loginError := (if (loginItem.username.isEmpty) None else Some(loginItem.isUsernameValid))
```

Answer (score 0):

According to [SLS](http://www.scala-lang.org/files/archive/spec/2.12/06-expressions.html), an `if` clause is an `Expr` but not a `SimpleExpr` or `PrefixExpr`.

Unfortunately, in the `InfixExpr` `a := b`, `b` must be a `PrefixExpr`.

That's why you have to use a temporary variable.